# Firebase Realtime works in Debug mode not in Run App mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code where I recover subscriptions. BillingClient checks and confirms if the payment is confirmed when my app is launched. I am trying to print a data to Firebase Realtime after payment is confirmed. This works fine in debug mode, but when I run it in app run mode it doesn't print this information to firebase. When I run it in debug mode and tick addValue, the code works flawlessly. What should I do? Please help me.

Thanks

```
 public void addValue(String productid, String token, String orderid, String signatur, String deviceId, String getUID, Long islemtime, String islem, String timem, String orjiJson) {
        String key = mDatabaseReference.child("/subs/").push().getKey();
        String languagename = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        Integer status = 0;
        Subscriptions subscriptions = new Subscriptions(productid, token, orderid, getUID, signatur, deviceId, languagename, islemtime, islem, timem, orjiJson, status);
        mDatabaseReference.child("/subs/").child(key).setValue(subscriptions, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                hideProgressDialogStatic();
                Intent n_act = new Intent(MyApplication.getInstance(), subfinish.class);
                n_act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                MyApplication.getInstance().startActivity(n_act);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So you that the `setValue()` operation fails?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ProGuard or any obfuscation in the release build, you'll need to use the `@Keep` annotation on your class.

Example:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep

@Keep
public class YourClass {}
```